# Unable to start Ubuntu system

Tags: boot

When I want try to start my laptop, it's showing a black screen with this message.

```
UBUNTU: clean, 1078873/7446528 files, 28320873/29755648 blocks
```

Comment: What video card/chip? What brand/model system.  The ext4 file system reports errors and on boot it checks. If clean you should have no file issues, but sometimes a full fsck is required like in Windows a full chkdsk is required. Often video issue is driver related and you may need boot parameter to boot. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  Can you also boot using recovery mode second entry in grub boot menu.

Comment: @oldfred grub boot menu also not showing. DELL Vostro 5581 core i5-8265U | 8GB DDR4 | 2GB Nvidia MX130

Comment: If dual booting it should show, unless you still have Windows fast start up on. Or you should be able to press Escape key right after Dell logo and before system starts booting to get grub menu. But if UEFI fast boot on, you may not have time to press any key. See if you can get grub menu. Have you updated UEFI from Dell? And if SSD updated firmware? Issues common across many model by brand. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420905